# setOnAction is not triggered

Tags: events, button, javafx

I require to display some text upon clicking a button.Here Button arraylist has been to added to vbox, the vbox to gridpane and  setOnAction  was invoked within Platform.runLater() method as shown.
code:

```
  private ArrayList<Button> btnar;
  private VBox vb;
  private Button downloadbtn;
@FXML
  private ScrollPane displayscroll;
   private GridPane gridpane;

 public HomeUI_2Controller() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         gridpane = new GridPane();
         displayscroll.setContent(gridpane);

         btnar = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filelist2.size(); i++) {
                downloadbtn = new Button("Download");
                btnar.add(downloadbtn);
            }
            int imageCol = 0;
            int imageRow = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < filelist2.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(filelist2.get(i).getName());

                image = new Image(filelist2.get(i).toURI().toString());

                pic = new ImageView();
                pic.setFitWidth(130);
                pic.setFitHeight(130);

                pic.setImage(image);
                vb = new VBox();
                vb.getChildren().addAll(pic, (Button) btnar.get(i));

                gridpane.add(vb, imageCol, imageRow);
                GridPane.setMargin(pic, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
                imageCol++;

                // To check if all the 3 images of a row are completed
                if (imageCol > 2) {
                    // Reset Column
                    imageCol = 0;
                    // Next Row
                    imageRow++;
                }

            }
             downloadbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("sssss");
                }
            });

    }
    });

}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `setOnAction()` inside `Platform.runLater` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Well, then what would be your suggestion?

Comment: Your approach has too many flaws. I am not able to get an idea of what you are trying to achieve. Your scrollPane is accessed from a `FXML`, whereas other layouts and controls are not. Inside your constructor, you have a `Platform.runLater`. Try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or edit your code as well as the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Only your last "Download" button should be triggered. Because you are adding the onAction event handler to the last one only.
- You don't need `Paltform.runLater()` here.
- You shouldn't construct identical multiple loops, if you can loop only once.
- Try to keep variable's scope as narrow as possible. In another words, don't define global variable and use everywhere as placeholder. This makes the code more error prone and difficult to maintain.

Test this refactored code:

```
private ArrayList<Button> btnar;
private VBox vb;
@FXML
private ScrollPane displayscroll;
private GridPane gridpane;

public HomeUI_2Controller() {

    gridpane = new GridPane();
    displayscroll.setContent(gridpane);

    btnar = new ArrayList<>();
    int imageCol = 0;
    int imageRow = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < filelist2.size(); i++) {
        Button downloadbtn = new Button("Download");
        downloadbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("You are requested to download the file " + filelist2.get(i).getName());
            }
        });
        btnar.add(downloadbtn);

        System.out.println(filelist2.get(i).getName());
        image = new Image(filelist2.get(i).toURI().toString());

        ImageView pic = new ImageView();
        pic.setFitWidth(130);
        pic.setFitHeight(130);

        pic.setImage(image);
        vb = new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(pic, downloadbtn);

        gridpane.add(vb, imageCol, imageRow);
        GridPane.setMargin(pic, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        imageCol++;

        // To check if all the 3 images of a row are completed
        if (imageCol > 2) {
            // Reset Column
            imageCol = 0;
            // Next Row
            imageRow++;
        }
    }
}
```